# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient can not restart ftp upload after connection failure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ftp, javafx, java-io

i am trying to implement a fallback mechanism for ftp upload in case of communication errors/timeouts etc. Actually what i am trying to achieve is that if a file is uploading (using a scheduler) and i have a connection failure then this file the next time that the scheduler is going to attempt and upload it should be able to re-initiate the file upload.

So my scheduler is calling every X minutes a method which is polling a directory for retrieving files to be send:

```
public void sendZippFiles() throws IOException, Exception {
    ...
    if (directoryListing2 != null) {
        for (File child : directoryListing2) {
            ...
            StudyDetailsDAO studyDetailsDAO = new StudyDetailsDAOImpl();
            TransferFileFtp ftpTransfer = new TransferFileFtp();

            // check if the file is in progress of uploading
            Boolean isInProgress = studyDetailsDAO.checkStudyDetailsIsInProgress(tmpStr);
            // check if the file is registered in local db - only registered files should be send
            Boolean studyExist = studyDetailsDAO.checkStudyDetailsExists(tmpStr);

            if(!isInProgress && child1.exists() && !child1.isDirectory() && studyExist) {
                 // set flag true to mark that the file is in progress of uploading
                 studyDetailsDAO.updateStudyIsInProgress(tmpStr, true);
                 // try and upload the file by calling a method to upload the file
                 Boolean toFtpTransfer = ftpTransfer.uploadFileFtp3(child1);
                 if (toFtpTransfer==true) {
                    //if success then a) rename remote file and delete file from local directory
                    ftpTransfer.renameFileFtp3(child1);
                    boolean delete = child1.delete();
                    //if success then update required flags to db
                    if(child1.toPath().toString().endsWith(".zip")) {
                    try {
                        studyDetailsDAO.updateStudyIsUploaded(tmpStr, true);
                        studyDetailsDAO.updateStudyIsInProgress(tmpStr, false);
                        studyDetailsDAO.updateIsReadyToProccess(tmpStr, false);
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        // if any error occurs
                        System.out.println("Error sending the file!");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        toFtpTransfer = false;
                    }                    
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error in file type!");
                        child1.delete();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("An error occured during file upload...");
                    // maybe here we should try and set IsInProgress to FALSE
                    studyDetailsDAO.updateStudyIsInProgress(tmpStr, false);
                }
                ....
```

and here is the method to upload a file: ftpTransfer.uploadFileFtp3(File)

```
public Boolean uploadFileFtp3(File sendFile) {
    Boolean ftpStatus = false;
    ....
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
          ...
          ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
          ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024000);
          File secondLocalFile = new File(sendFile.getCanonicalPath());
        String secondRemoteFile = config.getFtpRemoteFolderUploads()+sendFile.getName()+".part";

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(secondLocalFile); 

        System.out.println("Start uploading file");
        OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;
        int cc = 0;
        long fileSize = secondLocalFile.length();
        System.out.println("Start uploading file with size: " + fileSize);
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + read*(cc+1) + " of " + fileSize + " of file: " + sendFile.getName());
            cc++;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close(); 
        boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
        if (completed) {
            System.out.println("The file is uploaded successfully.");
            ftpStatus = true;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        error = true;
        ex.printStackTrace();            
        System.out.println("Going to update IsInProgress status for study: " + stdId);
        studyDetailsDAO.updateStudyIsInProgress(stdId, false);
        ftpStatus = false;

    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return ftpStatus;
}
```

So, the issue is the following: If a file upload is discrupted (communication error) the next time that the scheduler is trying to restart its upload i am receiving a NullPointerException:

```
Start uploading file
Start uploading file with size: 23783382
Ιαν 22, 2015 2:15:58 ΜΜ com.npap.dicomrouter2.FXMLDocumentController RunScheduledTasks
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.npap.network.TransferFileFtp.uploadFileFtp3(TransferFileFtp.java:240)
at com.npap.utils.ProcessDicomFiles.sendZippFiles(ProcessDicomFiles.java:165)
at com.npap.dicomrouter2.FXMLDocumentController.RunScheduledTasks(FXMLDocumentController.java:290)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the place that i am receiving the error is where i am trying to write to outputStream in the upload file method:

```
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + read*(cc+1) + " of " + fileSize + " of file: " + sendFile.getName());
            cc++;
        }
```

What am i missing here? should i somehow recreate a new OutputStream object? Is this the issue?

Comment: Is your `OutputStream` null? Try checking it by `if(outputStream==null)`

Comment: So if(outputStream==null) is should re-initiate the whole process? Build all required objects etc?

Comment: You must construct the object `OutputStream` somewhere so it isn't null

Comment: Where exactly? i have tried to initialize outputStream outside the try{} block and set it to ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile) afterwards. No matter what i have tried i am receiving the same NullPointerException ... Can you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: What I suggest you to do(I'm amusing you're calling the method again after the file fails to upload) is make a new class dedicated for file uploading(I'm not sure if you're doing the same thing or not). If the file fails to upload, call `new MyClass().uploadFileFtp3(file)` again.

Comment: In the first method (which is also called every time i am trying to upload the file) i am creating an instance of : TransferFileFtp ftpTransfer = new TransferFileFtp(); and then i am calling: boolean toFtpTransfer = ftpTransfer.uploadFileFtp4(child1);

Comment: You should add a null-check after `OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);`. I'm not familiar with Apache FTP client so I can't help you with this :\

Comment: In any case, Thanks for your feedback Jeremy.